# Go http handler route not registering, routing inconsistent

Tags: http, go, logging, build, handler

Fedora 33

go 1.15

I tried my hand at an API to take in data from my rasberry pi.  I had everything working last night, but when I tried running the server today via bash ./binary_file, only the "localhost:8080/" route was displaying.  If I tried to access my data endpoint, I got a socket disconnection error from postman and the python application sending data through requests.

I stopped getting logs from the "/api/data" route as if it was never receiving requests.  It is almost as if the route isn't being registered whatsoever all the sudden.  I did try removing the mux and directly calling http.HandleFunc, but the behavior was the same.

If I don't get the socket disconnect error, I get every route redirected to "/" (displays hello world).  If I comment out the ("/", root) route, all I see is 404 errors.

I'm not sure what could be going on.  Is there a way to see what routes are registered and print them out to confirm that is working as expected?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "database/sql"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.OpenFile("info.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    log.SetOutput(file)
    config := BuildConfigurations("config", "yml")
    db := GetDB(config.Database)

    handler := http.NewServeMux()
    handler.HandleFunc("/", root)
    handler.HandleFunc("/api/data", dataHandler(db))

    defer db.Close()
    http.ListenAndServe(config.Server.Address, handler)
}

func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `Hello World`)
}

func dataHandler(db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        err := r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error %s.  Could not parse MultipartForm.", err)
        }

        var dp dpacket
        dp.sid = r.FormValue("sid")
        dp.time = time.Now()
        dp.value, _ = strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("value"))
        dp.attachment, err = getFileFromRequest(r, "file")

        err = WriteData(db, dp)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error %s. Could not write to database.", err)
        }

        log.Printf("Data Received- SID: %s, TIME: %s, VALUE: %d", dp.sid, dp.time, dp.value)
    }
}

// getFileFromRequest attempts to read file
func getFileFromRequest(r *http.Request, key string) (fileAttachment, error) {
    var newAttachment fileAttachment
    file, header, err := r.FormFile(key)
    defer file.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("r.FormFile failed. %s", err)
        return newAttachment, err
    }

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    if _, err := io.Copy(buf, file); err != nil {
        return newAttachment, err
    }

    newAttachment.file = buf.Bytes()
    newAttachment.header = header
    log.Printf("File detected. Attempting to write with filename %s", header.Filename)

    return newAttachment, err
}
```

The entire repository can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/newnativeabq/goendpoint)

Comment: Please come up with a minimal example which exhibits your issue.

Answer (score 0):

if r.FormFile returns nil, nil, err for whatever reason, 'file' will be nil and defer file.close() will fail when the function returns, but not at compile time.